# How to increase 1 the value of a null field?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE users u SET events = events + 1 WHERE id u.id = new.user_id;
```

The default value of `event` column is `NULL`. So my query won't affect (increase). How can I handle that?

Comment: Use COALESCE() function regard a NULL as a 0

Answer (score 0):

try this way

Using `IFNULL()`

```
UPDATE users u SET events = IFNULL(events, 0) + 1 WHERE id u.id = new.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE() function regard a NULL as a 0

```
UPDATE users u SET events = COALESCE(events, 0) + 1 WHERE u.id = new.user_id;
```